# CakePHP pretty URL routes not working on production server only

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to use the following in my routes.php file:

```
Router::connect(
    "/:slug/:controller/:action/:id", 
    array('controller' => ":controller", 'action' => ':action'),
    array('id'=>'[0-9]','pass'=>array('id'))
);
```

This works fine on my test server but as soon as I upload to my production server I get a "Controller not found" error meaning CakePHP is trying to use the wrong route.

Normally I would think that it's a misconfiguration on the server somewhere but I am running other cakephp sites on this same server and the pretty URL routing is working absolutely fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify Regex condition for slug also ....

Comment: I'll give it a try. Strange that it would work fine on my test server though . . .

Comment: Strangely, if I put an echo "here"; in my routes.php file it doesn't show up on screen. I'm starting to think it's not finding my route.php file.

Comment: can you tell me how does your url look like

Comment: Here's the URL: http://blinds-brighton.co.uk/120-cm-wide-roller-blind/sizes/view/96

Comment: I think routeclass will help you Router::connect(
  '/:slug',
  array('controller'=>'controller','action'=>'action'),
  array('routeClass'=>'SlugRoute', 'pass' => array('id'))
 );

Comment: I've tried adding a routeClass but it only works on my test server. As soon as I upload it to my production server the router ignores it.

Comment: http://blinds-brighton.co.uk/sizes/view/96 is working but still giving  some errors

Comment: I tried deleting everything and reuploading and it worked! I have no idea why. Oh well, thanks very much for all your help!